# subprocess ssh command fails for some commands but not others (command works in terminal)

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, gnu-screen

As part of a python script, I am hoping to capture the output of a shell command executed via ssh, namely

`ssh User@999 screen -list`

If I execute the above command directly in terminal, I get the results I need.  However, when executing through `subprocess.check_output` as below, I get a `non-zero exit status 1` error.

I am able to execute other commands via ssh and capture the output without problem.
Is there something specific about `screen -list` that does not like being called in this fashion?

---

```
import subprocess 

srvr = 'User@999.99.999.9'

print("CMD 1: ===============")
cmd1 = "ssh " + srvr + " ls -l"
print ("COMMAND IS .....  " + cmd1 + "\n")
out1 = subprocess.check_output(cmd1, shell=True)
print(out1 + "\n")

print("CMD 2: ===============")
cmd2 = "ssh " + srvr + " screen -list"
print ("COMMAND IS .....  " + cmd2 + "\n")
out2 = subprocess.check_output(cmd2, shell=True)
print(out2 + "\n")
```

#### Error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ssh User@999.99.999.9 screen', '-list']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: Have you tried capturing some more output say from ``stderr`` of the child process(es)? This may give you a clue as to what's going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) check the exit code of the subprocess; and it raises exception if the exit code is not zero.

If you don't care about exit code, use [`subprocess.Popen.communicate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

```
out1, err1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

Comment: I was about to update my question that appending `; exit 0` to my command gets me the desired output.  Any drawback to that method?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, If you don't care about the exit code, I think it's okay. BTW, it will not work in Windows cmd.

Answer (score 0):

That's how `subprocess.check_output()` is supposed to work. See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

The command on your server is returning a non zero return code and thus is raising the appropriate Exception `CalledProcessError`.

Comment: while what you say is accurate, it really provides no _useful_ information

Comment: Sorry about that. Was writing while on the go.